# Python - none returns from try and except clauses

Tags: python, function, validation, date, try-except

the return from this code (date) is 'none' if an invalid entry is provided, then a valid entry is given. However if a valid entry is given first time, the correct return for date is given. Any tips on how I can solve it?

```
def getDate():
    date = input("Please enter the date in DD/MM/YYYY format: ")
    try:
        strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
        return date
    except:
        print ("Invalid Date, please enter again")
        getDate()
```

Comment: 1. You don't return anything in the `except` case. 2. [Don't use bare `except`](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/). 3. Don't use recursion for this - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761

Comment: You can make it work by changing the last line in the `except` clause to  `return getDate()`. But you shouldn't use recursion, as jonrsharpe points out, to perform retries; use a loop instead.

Comment: The reason for closing this question seems completely wrong. It _can_ be reproduced and it is (probably) not a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are so many erroneous answers being posted to this question I feel compelled to add another. Adding `return getDate()` in the except clause will make it work as you hope:

```
def getDate():
    date = input("Please enter the date in DD/MM/YYYY format: ")
    try:
        strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
        return date
    except:
        print ("Invalid Date, please enter again")
        return getDate()
```

However, handling retries with recursion is not ideal. Use a loop instead:

```
from time import strptime

def getDate():
    while True:
        date = input("Please enter the date in DD/MM/YYYY format: ")
        try:
            strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
            return date
        except ValueError:
            print ("Invalid Date, please enter again")
```

Comment: Don't you need to `return strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")` rather than `return date`?

Comment: Nope. The `strptime` call is just to ensure that `date` is a valid (proper format) date string.

Comment: @JamieBull: why? `strptime()` is being used only to validate the user entered string, and the function returns the string, not whatever object `strptime()` returns (a `time.struct_time` in my case).

Comment: By the way, I would put the `return date` in an `else`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: why? Does it make a difference in this case?

Comment: I don't expect `return date` to throw a `ValueError`, no, but it's a good practice, and I think it clarifies the algorithm ("try this, if it fails do this, if it succeeds do that").